# SQL Query : Is it possible to project a four results in a single query?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Currently, I am executing four queries to project the results based last 24hours, last week, last month and last month. Is it possible to project a four results in a single query?

Comment: Oracle or Postgres? Those are two different DBMS products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need last one week, last one month, last one year compared to current date then you can do it using conditional aggregation in oracle as following:

```
Select sum(case when trunc(date_col) = trunc(sysdate-1) then 1 end) as last_one_day,
sum(case when trunc(date_col) between trunc(sysdate-7) and trunc(sysdate-1) then 1 end) as last_one_week,
sum(case when trunc(date_col) between trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1)) and trunc(sysdate-1) then 1 end) as last_one_month,
sum(case when trunc(date_col) between trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12)) and trunc(sysdate-1) then 1 end) as last_one_year
From your_table
Where type = ...
```

Cheers!!